# In kubernetes can ```service.spec.sessionAffinityConfig.clientIP.timeoutSeconds``` be set to infinity?

Tags: kubernetes, service

As described in the title, can `service.spec.sessionAffinityConfig.clientIP.timeoutSeconds` be specified to infinity? I want the sessions never to change pod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [api docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.10/#clientipconfig-v1-core) timeoutSeconds specifies the seconds of ClientIP type session sticky time. The value must be >0 && <=86400(for 1 day) if ServiceAffinity == "ClientIP". Default value is 10800(for 3 hours).

So it can not be infinity.